# Monotouch.Dialog alternative for Unified DLL

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Part of the guide says to remove all references that have the Monotouch prefix. This includes `Monotouch.Dialog` and many others. But it doesn't say what it replace it with.

What can I use to replace this reference so that I can make use of things like `RadioGroup` and other items like `GPUImage`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MonoTouch.Dialog is still available in the Unified API, however it's a special case in that the `MonoTouch` namespace prefix has not been removed.

In other words it's still called MonoTouch.Dialog.

Comment: Ok thanks. And what about if I need to use GPUImage ? I realise it is not in the same DLL

Comment: I don't know anything about GPUImage.

Comment: I am sorry, I see now that it is a third party library. Thank you for your help.